# Как определить для каждой column1 макс значение column3 и вывести column2

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица:

```
ethnicity | item | count
```

Надо для каждой ethnicity найти item с наибольшим количеством count и вывести эти 3 колонки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (SELECT ethnicity, item, "count", 
               -- для каждого ethnicity нумеруем записи по убыванию count
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ethnicity ORDER BY "count" DESC) rn
        FROM source_table)
SELECT ethnicity, item, "count"
FROM cte
-- для каждого ethnicity берём только запись номер 1 (с максимальным count)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Желательно наличие индекса по `(ethnicity, "count")`.

---

Если несколько записей имеют одинаковый и в то же время максимальный `"count"`, запрос выведет одну случайную запись из них.

Если требуется вывести одну определённую (например, с минимальным `item`) - расширьте соответствующим образом сортировку в определении окна (например, `(PARTITION BY ethnicity ORDER BY "count" DESC, item ASC)`). Желательно, чтобы такая сортировка была уникальной для группы.

Если же в таком случае требуется вывести все такие записи, а не одну из них, замените `ROW_NUMBER()` на `RANK()` либо `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```sql
with grouped as 
  (
     select t1.ethnicity, max(count) count
       from Table1 t1
     group by t1.ethnicity
  )
select grouped.ethnicity, t.item, grouped.count from grouped
inner join Table1 t
on t.ethnicity = grouped.ethnicity and t.count = grouped.count;
```

Тест [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d9d785/7/0).